# Error : Call to undefined method addAttributeToFilter()

Tags: php, magento, collections, model

I have made my Magento Model :

```
<?php

class Kiwi_SliderBoard_Model_Resource_Slider_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
         $this->_init("sliderboard/slider");

    }

}
```

Whene i try to use it on my block :

```
class Kiwi_SliderBoard_Block_Slider extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract {

    public  function getSlider ()
    {
        $slider= Mage::getModel('sliderboard/slider')
                 ->getCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));
        return  $slider;
  }

}
```

I got this Error !

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Kiwi_SliderBoard_Model_Resource_Slider_Collection::addAttributeToFilter()
>   in
>   C:\wamp\www\ce_1.6.2.0\app\code\local\Kiwi\SliderBoard\Block\Slider.php
>   on line 8

Can you  help !
Thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
addAttributeToFilter();
```

is only used for the EAV Collections like products, customers, etc.

for all the other collections just use :

```
addFieldToFilter();
```